# Parse API: batch push notifications

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, push, batch-processing

I'm wondering how push notifications can be sent in batches. Let's look at the problem from the following 3 major patterns:

1. one API call -> one message -> delivered to a specified user
2. one API call -> one messages -> delivered to many different users (specified by id)
3. one API call -> many different messages -> delivered to many different users (specified by id)

The first one can be done easily.

The question is, what would you recommend to use for the second and the third ones?

I'm thinking of something similar to Facebook's Batch Requests when you have the ability to pass instructions for several operations in a single HTTP request. Is it possible at all with Parse?

Answer (score 0):

for second pattern there is a way.
where parameter should be like this: `where={"id":{"$in":[1,3,5,7,9]}}`

more where parameters:
[image: Parse API where Parameters]

another example if you need to execute query for fining IDs:
[image: Parse API push example]

still no workaround for third pattern